# How to code hosting of the WF with WC 3.5 ReciveActivity in Windows Service (XP)?

Tags: windows, wcf, service, hosting, workflow-foundation

I created a small VS solution that includes WF with WCF ReceiveActivity project (using basicHttpBinding) and a number of plain C# services. They all work perfectly when tested from VS 2008 using WCFTestClient.

I deployed them into a single Windows Service.  All but WF service work fine. I spent 6 hours browsing, but didn’t find a solution that works. Please help.

Comment: Maurice,

Thank you much for your post, I will follow up your guideline.  The reason I was using the basicHttpBinding is that I’m trying to do things incrementally. First establish hosting with the simplest configuration and then move forward with the real binding.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the WorkflowServiceHost instead of the normal ServiceHost. The  WorkflowServiceHost does all the usual WCF related stuff but also makes sure a workflow runtime is created and the required workflow routing environment is setup.

See [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/03/19/receiveactivity-and-self-hosting-wcf.aspx) blog post for how to do so. This [second post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/03/20/configuring-a-self-hosted-receiveactivity-and-its-runtime.aspx) show a bit more about how to change the configuration.

BTW. In general you should be using the context bindings like the basicHttpContextBinding and wsHttpContextBinding as they pass the context information containing the workflow instanceId with the messages.

Comment: The Answer from Maurice and the links he provided closed the question.

Thank you Maurice. You disserve all points repeated to this post